# Need to render HTML with Play parameters

Tags: html, playframework

I have an object that has a title and some text (item.itmTitle and item.itmText) which I am passing to an HTML template using Play's render() method. Within the template (which in this case is called "index.html) I am trying to display the contents of the item object:

.
.
.
<p class="title">${item.itmTitle}</p>
<div id="itemtext">${item.itmText}</div>
.
.
.

My problem is this: the contents of item.itmText are HTML formatted. What I would like is for the contents to be displayed as HTML, but what is happening is that Play is doing all necessary conversions to display the contents as text. In other words, if item.itmText has the following HTML:

<p>This is a paragraph formatted in HTML</p>

The play template converts the source as follows:

& lt;p& gt;This is a paragraph formatted in HTML& lt;/p& gt;

My question is: is there some way to stop this conversion and make the HTML appear on the page as renderable HTML?

Someone please advise.

Answer (score 6):

```
${item.itmTitle.raw()}
```

You just need to make sure that these strings are guaranteed to be safe; e.g. if users are submitting the title or text you need to sanitize the content to prevent injection of javascript (or accidental breakage of your container tags).

Comment: Or [verbatim](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/tags#verbatim) for more than just one item.